# drag div on exact mouse point

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

I'm trying to drag an element with just vanilla JavaScript.

When I drag the element I want it to move in sync with where the mouse pointer clicked, I can move it via the elements top left corner which is simple enough but I'm having issues moving it from the exact point of click.

**Javascript**

```
function mouseMove(e){
    if(dragging){
        boxPos(sq,e);
    }
}
function boxPos(el,e){
    box = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse_top = e.clientY;
    mouse_left = e.clientX;
    diff_x = mouse_left - box.left;
    diff_y = mouse_top - box.top;
    el.style.top = (mouse_top + diff_y) +"px";
    el.style.left = (mouse_left + diff_x) +"px";
 }
```

`sq` is a div, `e` is the event.

What im trying to do is calculate the position of the mouse, work out the difference from the top/left and add it to the top left but I'm getting undesired results. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bw4yK/)

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been passed some years but, testing the Fiddle, I figured out that (at least to me) the answer isn't exactly what the OP was looking for. That's because in the response's Fiddle the div is moved perfectly but it's moved always on its origin (0,0) and not where it was exactly clicked.

The solution is actually quite simple.

You are calculating the `diff_x` and `diff_y` on every `mousemove` event. But the mouse pointer position while moving is always fixed in relation to the div at the very start of the `mousedown` event until firing the `mouseup` event, right? So, just declare the diffs' variables globally and calculate them on the `mousedown` event.

Then, change the following code:

```
function boxPos(el,e){
   box = el.getBoundingClientRect();
   mouse_top = e.clientY;
   mouse_left = e.clientX;
   diff_x = mouse_left - box.left;
   diff_y = mouse_top - box.top;
   el.style.top = (mouse_top + diff_y) +"px";
   el.style.left = (mouse_left + diff_x) +"px";
}
```

To:

```
function boxPos(el,e){
   box = el.getBoundingClientRect();
   mouse_top = e.clientY;
   mouse_left = e.clientX;
   el.style.top = (mouse_top - diff_y) +"px";
   el.style.left = (mouse_left - diff_x) +"px";
}
```

The diffs' math is done on the `mousedown` event, so we don't need it anymore. Thus, this will stop the flickering.

Besides that, as the diffs will always be positive, we just subtract the diffs from the corresponding mouse coordinates to place the div taking into account the difference calculated (because the mouse pointer must be on top of the div to trigger the `mousedown` event, then `e.clientY >= sq.style.top` and `e.clientX >= sq.style.left` will be always true). This last step is the one that moves the element on exact mouse point.

This logic may be used on other "dragging events", like the `dragstart` and `drag` events, `touchstart` and `touchmove` events and `pointerdown` and `pointermove` events as well (with some adaptation, of course). So, since this kind of behaviour may be relevant, I decided to post this answer. I hope it helps future readers.

Here's the OP's modified [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2na3u8q/3/).

Answer (score 0):

A quick hotfix would be:

change

```
el.style.top = (mouse_top + diff_y) +"px";
el.style.left = (mouse_left + diff_x) +"px";
```

to

```
el.style.top = (Number(el.style.top.split("px")[0]) + diff_y) +"px";
el.style.left = (Number(el.style.left.split("px")[0]) + diff_x) +"px";
```

or

```
el.style.top = (Number(el.style.top.replace("px", "")) + diff_y) +"px";
el.style.left = (Number(el.style.left.replace("px", "")) + diff_x) +"px";
```

You need to move that div from its old position to the new one using the old coordinates and the calculated difference. To get the old position I used the current `top` and `left` setting, removed the *"px"* from it and converted it to a number. This is necessary to avoid string concatenation (top and left are string values).

Your program has another bug ... you currently can't stop the dragging mode.

**Edit**

To remove the drag "stop" bug you could subtract 1 pixel from the new value, so the mouse pointer would still be inside the div and the mouse up event will be triggered correctly.
You can do that like this:

```
el.style.top = ((Number(el.style.top.replace("px", "")) - 1) + diff_y) +"px";
el.style.left = ((Number(el.style.left.replace("px", "")) - 1) + diff_x) +"px";
```

Here is the new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bw4yK/3/).